# Why do rockets sometimes climbs down before reaching orbital velocity?

Tags: launch, ariane

Looking at this [Ariane 5 launch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgj0kSXEtdQ&t=32m30), I notice that:

- the speed continously increase (as I expected)
- the altitude first increase as I expected, then decrease (I was not expecting that) and then increase again.

When looking at the graph on the right upper corner, it looks like a totally calculated maneuvre. The slight altitude decrease is obvious around 30 minutes in the linked video.

Why do the trajectory of this rocket include a temporary loss of altitude for several minutes before increasing again the altitude?